# "Your connection is not private" on paypal payment

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am integrating the pay-pal payment gateway to my site. 
And when i am clicking on "Login" to paypal account then it auto redirected to www.sandbox3.paypal.com and showing

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.sandbox3.paypal.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

So when i click on proceed to `www.sandbox3.paypal.com` then it show me to login and then payment process is halt. i am tired searching Please help me out

Comment: The Certificate is not valid. I guess you use https?

Comment: You should be able to safely ignore this error for test / sandbox testing.

Comment: @all thanks for reply . Yes i am using https:// to my site.

Comment: @jon i am ignoring this safety check but it is not allowing me to pay so that i can complete the payment.

Comment: You have to be more specific about where it is going wrong and how. Are you getting requested to input card details? Is it sending you back to your site? etc etc

Comment: @jon Let me explain you. I am using User Front end pro wordpress plugin and user registered to my site have to pay some amount to create posts on site so user have to purchase a subscription package. so when a user is going to checkout site is redirected to the paypal login page and when i login then this error page with message "Your Connection is not private" appears. and when i am proceeding to payapl url  www.sandbox3.paypal.com then it simply logins to my sandbox account and the payment process is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it without ssl i.e on http if it supports then the problem is at your ssl and make sure that you configured your ssl certificate properly and this problem commonly occurs if your https site is redirecting to another https site by some insecure content so use plugin named wp-force ssl so i could help you !
else make sure that you given production keys at keys option so that it could help you !
else make sure that you are using a valid certificate as if take a look over error provided by you  " NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID "
itself says that you have some error with ssl , try solving that